# Replace file names in folders and subfolders with bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

This code works when I do it for ONE folder (when I remove /r option before FOR loop), but when I enable /r option, it can see the files, but it can't rename them.

I want to rename the middle of the file from "-24px" to "lol"

```
@echo on
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /r %%F in (*-24px*) do (
  set filename="%%F"
  ren "!filename!" "!filename:-24px=lol!"
)
```

As I have mentioned, it can see the file and its' path, but throws syntax error

**Output:**

```
(
  set filename="C:\node_project\fold\1-24px1"
  ren !filename! !filename:-24px=lol!
)
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Comment: I cannot believe that quotes disappeared in your output (see `ren` command)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason: `ren` destination is the filename only - no path. Syntax:

```
REN [drive:][path]filename1 filename2
```

Your `!filename!` is a full path when you use `/R`.

The solution:

Get the filename.ext with `%%~nxF` (see `for /?` to read more about those modifiers) and change the `ren` syntax accordingly: the full path (source) would then be `"%%F"` and the destination would be the adapted `"!filename!"`:

```
@echo on
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /r %%F in (*-24px*) do (
  set filename="%%~nxF"
  ren "%%F" "!filename:-24px=lol!"
)
```